# Cannot install ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros, openni, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am having a problem installing ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04. The problem appears to be related to Openni/PCL binaries.

I am tyring to install ros-hydro-desktop. I have a x64 machine (might be the problem)

I used to have ROS Fuerte installed, but completely removed it.
Steps taken:

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-fuerte-ros
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I also update to the the distribution.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

When I try to install ROS hydro

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop
```

I get the following response

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-hydro-desktop : Depends: ros-hydro-viz but it is not going to be installed
```

Digging deeper into this leads to the following problem

```
ps-engine : Depends: openni-dev (>= 1.5.2.23~precise)
```

However, when trying to install "openni-dev", I get the following version installed:

```
Get:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main openni-dev amd64 1.3.2.1-4+precise2
```

They are clearly different versions of this package. I tried going to [openni](http://www.openni.org/openni-sdk/openni-sdk-history-2/) but this did not solve the problem.

I followed the installation instruction from the wiki (added deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main   to    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list)

These are the threads I have been reading that are related to this problem but do not offer a direct solution

[link1](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/1895)

[link2](http://answers.ros.org/question/78541/issues-installing-openni-packages-in-ros-groovyhydro/)

[link3](http://answers.ros.org/question/76495/hydro-openni-apt-get-problem/)

Any feedback/ideas will be greatly appreciated. I have spent several hours on this and not getting closer :S

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115546/cannot-install-ros-hydro-on-ubuntu-12.04/) by [pmolina](https://answers.ros.org/users/2919/pmolina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2014-01-07

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmolina](https://answers.ros.org/users/2919/pmolina/) on 2014-01-07**:
This is an actual current problem.
I still do not quite understand the position of ROS support on this.
Check this very interested thread this is still ongoing....

http://www.pcl-users.org/PCL-installation-unmet-dependency-problem-td4030129.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you might have added jochen sprickerhof's ppa for PCL, which interferes with hydro.

Removing it with the following command solved the problem for me:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl
```

---

Originally posted by [sebsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/23/sebsch/) with karma: 790 on 2014-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmolina](https://answers.ros.org/users/2919/pmolina/) on 2014-06-07**:
Thank you very much! You are a savior! This solves most of the problems - I can now install all openni stuff without problems. I have no idea why I had that on my ppas (guess better be careful what is on my ppas from now on)

**Comment by [edward](https://answers.ros.org/users/1253/edward/) on 2014-07-16**:
Hero of the day. Would never had figured this out myself (busy 3 hours trying to install Hydro besides Groovy)

**Comment by [Adnan Munawar](https://answers.ros.org/users/11796/adnan-munawar/) on 2014-11-04**:
Precisely, this had been a common occurance for a long time and many other workaround get you stuck somewhere in the future, like installing turtlebot etc on hydro. Thanks for the proper fix.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally fixed this problem.
I still do not think this is a solution, but so far it has not given me any trouble.

The problem is certainly rooted on the version of openni-dev package. I have no idea why the version currently online is 1.3.2 ...either way, this causes the package "ps-engine" to fail to install since it requires openni-dev 1.5.4 or later.

However, I installed aptitude and installed the openni-dev 1.3.2 and forced an install of an old version of ps-engine (5.2)... this however appears to play well with the PCL drivers and hence with the rest of ROS. I have however not tested this functionality, so I might run into other problems later.

Please read this thread for a full description of this:
http://www.pcl-users.org/PCL-installation-unmet-dependency-problem-td4030129.html

Final commands used:

```
sudo aptitude install ps-engine
```

This will ask if it is OK to install the old version of ps-engine with the old openni-dev package (1.3) - press Y on this question.
After this

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop
```

Will complete without major problems.

I hope this helps other people with this problem.

Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [pmolina](https://answers.ros.org/users/2919/pmolina/) with karma: 108 on 2014-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vikas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1768/vikas/) on 2014-01-22**:
Just a clarification: After "sudo aptitude install ps-engine" first option will be to not install ps-engine. It should be rejected with "n" and then the next option will be to install older version of ps-engine which should be accepted.